# How to execute servlet using Http request?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, apache-httpcomponents

I created a `servlet` that copies an uploaded file from `Uploading.jsp` page. Everything works perfectly in browser. I'm looking for a way to make a `servlet` to be executed by HTTP Request. It seems that the code below doesn't execute the `servlet` code.

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/Uploading.jsp");
        FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File("D:\\test1.xlsx"));
        HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
                .addPart("file", bin)
                .build();
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        try {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            if (resEntity != null) {
                System.out.println("ToString:" + EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
            }
            EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);

        }
        finally {
            response.close();
            System.out.println("response closed");
        }
    }
    finally {
        httpclient.close();
        System.out.println("http client closed");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Try using a `HttpGet` instead of `HttpPost`.

Comment: You need to post the request directly to the Servlet instead of the JSP because here you need to simulate what the JSP does, which is "I believe" pick a file and submit a form, requesting the JSP in the URL doesn't do anything unless you handled receiving the file using scriptlet within your JSP then you automatically submitted the form to the servlet.